# Why Instantiating a object and a pointer of object behaves differently when I create a thread in constructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, constructor

I have a class and in the constructor of a class I want to start a thread. Hence I called this->mythread = std::thread(foo).
Now if I create object of the class function foo executes and I can see a print by foo function i.e. "foo.. foo.. foo.. "
This behaviour is different when I create a pointer of the class, in this case the function foo is not executed at all.
Here I have mentioned my code, can someone go through the code and let me know what is happening here ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void foo() {
    cout << "foo.. foo.. foo.." << endl;
}

class test {
    public:
        test();
        ~test();

    private:
        std::thread m_thread;
};

test::test() {
    this->m_thread = std::thread(foo);
}
test::~test() {
    m_thread.join();
}

int main() {
    test t;                 // function foo() executes
    test *t1 = new test;    // function foo() does not executes
    test *t1 = new test();  // function foo() does not executes

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before `main` ends, destructor of `t` local variable is called and thread is joined. You need to call `detete t1` to explicitly join t1 thread.

Answer (score 0):

Both `t` and `t1` are local variables. When `main` ends, these objectes are destroyed, in case of `t` its destructor is called which invokes `join` on thread and you can see the body of thread i.e. "foo" on console. In case of `t1` memory for storing pointer is released but destructor of `test` is not called - you have to call `delete t1` to explicitly call dtor of `test`. Then `main` returns only if `foo` function (as body of thread) is completed, and you will see the same result as creating `t`.